# nonlinear steps and keyboard input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

http://jsfiddle.net/E7B7k/1/

js:

```
    Math.easeIn = function (val, min, max, strength) {
    val /= max;
    return (max-1)*Math.pow(val, strength) + min;
};

$('.slide-me').slider({
  min: 1,
  max: 1000000,
  slide: function(e, ui){
    var y = Math.easeIn(ui.value, 1, 1000000, 2.5);
    $('#amount').val(Math.round(y));

    $('input').change(function(e) {switch (this.id) {case "amount":$('.slide-me').slider("value", $('#amount').val())
                              break;}})

  }

});
```

html:

```
<div class="slide-me"></div><input type="text" id="amount" style="" />
```

So After switching the keyboard the nonlinear step disappears

Comment: you showed your code, you even made an example, but you failed to properly explain what is wrong :(

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "after switching the keyboard the nonlinear step disappears"?

Comment: @mgerstner try to change the value from the keyboard. slider to change the value as step one